# interacting with console app using java

Tags: java, macos, console, command

i want to open an external app using java.

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Users/kausar/myApp");
```

this runs the process as i can see in activity monitor.
Now the file i run is actually console app which then takes commands and gives response based on those commands.
for example if i go to terminal and put the same

```
    Kausars-MacBook-Air:~ kausar$ /Users/kausar/myApp
    myApp>
```

Now i can give commands to app as for example

```
    myApp> SHOW 'Hi There'
```

These are commands taken as keyboard input in the console app, these are not parameters. I have seen different approaches with parameters. I tried the following as well but couldnt get it to work.

```
     String res;        
     String cmnd = "SHOW \'Hi There\'";
     OutputStream stdin = null;
    InputStream stdout = null;
    stdout = p.getInputStream();
    stdin = p.getOutputStream();

    stdin.write(cmnd.getBytes());
    stdin.flush();
    p.waitFor();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(stdout));
          while ((res = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(res)
          }
          input.close();

    p.destroy();
```

Its displaying nothing while the same procedure with "/bin/bash -c ls" works just fine.
please help!

Comment: You are defining stderr as input stream and assigning p.getInptStream to stdout.

Comment: @Guanxi corrected it , that was probably copy paste mistake, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Of hand I would say the problem is with p.**wait**For()
Exactly what object and when to usee notify() or notifyAll() call to wake up the object thread would be something like on stdout and maybe a restructure of the process.
note: an interesting feature is the class field in BufferedReader called "lock", the api docs do mention some way of structuring your program so it can be notified.